# Which linting tool to use for Angular with JHipster

Tags: eslint, jhipster, lint

I've recently discovered JHipster and I'm giving it a try. Reading the [official web page](https://www.jhipster.tech/code-quality/#-code-quality), it says that JHipster uses Sonar as its linting tool. But I've also noticed that the project has a `.eslintrc.json` file configured to work with Angular and Eslint dependencies/scripts in `package.json`. However, the `sonar-project.properties` file isn't configured to import Eslint's report into SonarQube (via `sonar.eslint.reportPaths`).

So I'm left wondering how the linting analisis should be done with JHipster's stack. Am I supposed to use sonar-scanner's report or import Eslint's report into SonarQube?

Thanks in advance,

Urko

Answer (score 1):

JHipster uses SonarQube to analyze your java source code and usually this is done by your build tool (maven or gradle) and/or your java IDE.

Then there's static code analysis for frontend code which can be run using `npm lint` and which uses eslint. JHipster does not configure `.eslintrc.json` to use `eslint-plugin-sonarjs` so there's no link with Sonar here but you could add it if you want to use additional eslint rules provided by Sonar.